# Search Index deleted content over weekend - cannot do full crawl

Tags: search, crawling

I've had a SharePoint 2010 server running since March, with a crawl containing around 32,000 searchable items. The crawling was setup to perform an incremental crawl nightly and a full crawl weekly. Until this last weekend it's been working just fine.

However, on Friday night when the last full crawl ran, it deleted every item from the index, and now when I try a full crawl it completes after 1 minute 40 seconds, with a single Top Level Error - `http://myserver01:100 - The crawler could not communicate with the server. Check that the server is available and that the firewall access is configured correctly.`

The server at `http://myserver01:100` is extended to port 443 (for public access), and that extended web application works just fine. I can use the public facing side of the web application just fine, except for crawling.

If I remote desktop into the server box and try to access `http://myserver01:100` I get errors saying that `The resource object with key 'personalactions_menu_ak' was not found`. This makes me think two things:

1. The web application at `http://myserver01:100` is running, otherwise there wouldn't be any .NET errors (it would just show something like a HTTP 503 error?), and
2. There is a problem with the base web application - probably permissions. The error is saying that an out of the box resource key from wss.resx (which is confirmed as being in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\100\App_GlobalResources`). I don't know if this would impact the crawl or not, as I would expect the crawl to look at the content database rather than try to render the pages?

I could really use some help trying to work out why my crawls won't work any more, and/or if the error with the resource keys might be the issue, and if so, how to resolve them. Again, they are the out of the box wss.resx files causing the issue, which I've not changed at all. I did add a custom resx file, but that's not appearing in the error messages.

Any ideas?

Kevin

Comment: Where did you add the custom RESX file? I've seen issues with resx files in the App_GlobalResources when SharePoint doesn't consider them to be "valid". Have you tried remove the custom file?

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but I did just remove my custom resx file, but the error with the site remains. I don't know if the error seen in the browser is a red herring or not, as surely the search service uses the content database when crawling, so theoretically seeing an error in a browser shouldn't impact this (plus I think the error with `wss,personalactions_menu_ak` has been around for a while, and the search crawls still worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the line in the web.config that was causing the problem, though I'm still not exactly sure why.

```
<globalization resourceProviderFactoryType="Communifire.Providers.LocalizationProviders.DyveResourceProviderFactory, Communifire.Providers" />
```

The Communifire application is a 3rd party system we use for Social Networking, and my SharePoint site uses some Single Sign On code to allow SP authenticated users to get access to the social area without double login. On the 443 site this item in the web.config seems to work just fine, but on the 100 site, it didn't.
At least now I know.